# How to apply OData $select after Couchbase IQueryable is executed

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, couchbase

I’m trying to implement OData functionality in a web api coupled to a Couchbase bucket using the [convention model builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/convention-model-builder) for the Entity Data Model (EDM), with endpoints in .NET Core 3.1 and using these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="CouchbaseNetClient" Version="2.7.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Linq2Couchbase" Version="1.4.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.4.0-beta" />
```

In this first version I return an IQueryable linked to a POCO matching the document to list Client documents.

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Client> Get([FromServices]ICouchbaseService context)
    => context.BucketContext.Query<Client>();
```

How OData uses the Queryable to apply the select isn’t possible with Couchbase.

```
// Couchbase.Linq.CouchbaseQueryException: An error occurred executing the N1QL query.  See the inner exception for details.
//  ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
//    at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandWrapperConverter.ReadJson(
//    Couchbase.N1QL.QueryClient.ExecuteQueryAsync[T](IQueryRequest queryRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here the $select does work, but this has the disadvantage that $top and $skip won't run as LIMIT and OFFSET on the database.

```
// localhost:5000/odata/Client?$select=Address/Street,Name
[EnableQuery]
public Task<IEnumerable<Client>> Get()
{
    return this.clientRepository.GetAll().ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Workaround ideas I have, is to apply the $top and $skip myself to the Couchbase query or not use $select at all.

Which is a proper approach to have $select working? i.e. don't apply the $select on the `IQueryable` but only on the retrieved results afterwards.

Are there any .NET examples where Couchbase and OData are used together?

Comment: would you mind posting a full example to GitHub or something? I'd like to try to work through it, see where this NotImplementedException is. Maybe I could work on a pull request for Linq2Couchbase.

Comment: Also, this may not be what you're looking for, but I know CData has an OData API product for Couchbase - https://www.cdata.com/drivers/couchbase/odata/

Comment: Thanks. I've put a sample project on https://github.com/ofthelit/ODataCouchbase

Comment: This is a really good sample, thanks @ofthelit. I'm not sure if this is a bug, or just not yet supported, but I opened up an issue on the Linq2Couchbase repo here: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Linq2Couchbase/issues/284